# What's the equivalent thing as ServletContextListener for Java

Tags: playframework-2.0

I would ask what's the equivalent thing for Play as `ServletContextListener` for Java web.

During the application starts up, I would fetch data from DB and save in memory/cache, and other things that is similar and suitable to be done during server startups

In the Java web world, this is usually hooked into `ServletContextListener#contextIntialized`

I searched stackoverflow,there were some answers there,but had been out dated

Comment: could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a complete answer without knowing exactly what "initialization work" you're doing. But I'd suggest a good place to start would be by declaring a `Module` [as documented in the Play DI documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Providing-custom-bindings).

If you write a basic `Module` that extends `AbstractModule`:

```
package modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.{ Configuration, Environment }

class MyModule(
  environment: Environment,
  configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {

  def configure() = {
    ...
  }
}
```

and enable that in your `application.conf`:

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.MyModule"
```

You've got a great place to act on your app's `Environment` and `Configuration` settings.

The documentation doesn't really go into it, but in here you can also call interesting methods like `bindListener()` which will allow you to be notified as each of your declared dependencies gets "provisioned" by Google Guice. There's a vast amount of stuff that you can do once you're hooked into Guice - perhaps start at the Guice documentation [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections).

Comment: Thanks @millihouse, I am able to do the initialization with `Module`