# Play Json framework can't parse json string if some field doesn't exist

Tags: scala, playframework

I defined a case class Fruit:

```
case class Fruit(name: String, weight: Double)
```

I wrote an action to save a fruit

```
  def saveFruit = Action(parse.json) { request: Request[JsValue] =>
    import models.Implicits._
    val json = request.body
    val fruitResult = Json.fromJson[Fruit](json)
    if (fruitResult.isSuccess) {
      val fruit = fruitResult.get
      println(fruit)
      Ok(JsString("1"))
    } else {
      Ok(JsString("2"))
    }

  }
```

If the request body is `{ "name":"ABC","weight":10}`, then the action will be successfully called.

If the request body is `{ "name":"ABC"}`,then an error occurs,complaining that the `weight` is not undefined on object

`{ "name":"ABC"}` is a valid json string that can't parsed as a Fruit and weight will be null

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

I am using Play 2.6.0

Comment: looks like you want `Fruit` to use optional values? `name: Option[String], weight: Option[Double]`?

Comment: Thanks @tgk  for the answer. I got another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187140/whats-the-equivalent-thing-as-servletcontextlistener-for-java, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest not going down the rabbit hole of allowing `null` anywhere. If you start allowing this in your request objects, you will never know whether there's a null anywhere in your models.

The typical way to approach this is to set this to `Option` as was suggested in the comments.

If you're working on a more elaborate solution, it might make sense to create dedicated request objects with lots of `Option`s for values where the client might not send a value. You would then map/transform the request objects into your domain model in the controller and validate the input accordingly.

For example:

```
case class FruitRQ(name: String, weight: Option[Double])

case class Fuit(name: String, weight: Double)

class MyController {

  def myAction = {
    val fruitRq = Json.fromJson[FruiteRQ](request.body)
    (for (weight <- fruitRq.weight) yield {
      val fruit = Fruit(fruitRq.name, weight)
      // do something with the validate fruit
    }).getOrElse {
      // return 4xx to client saying that a field is missing
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rethab for the answer. I got another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187140/whats-the-equivalent-thing-as-servletcontextlistener-for-java, could you please take a look?